# how to get file from resources as a stream? (.net)

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I've got few files in resources (xsd files) that i use for validating received xml messages. The resource file i use is named **AppResources.resx** and it contains a file called **clientModels.xsd**. When i try to use the file like this: AppResources.clientModels, i get a string with the file's content. i would like to get a stream instead.
i do not wish to use assembly.GetManifestResourceStream as i had bad experiences with it (using these streams to archive files with SharpZipLib didn't work for some reason).
is there any other way to do it? i've heard about ResourceManager - is it anything that could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you feed the string you get into a System.IO.StringReader, perhaps? That may do what you want. You may also want to check out MemoryStream.

Answer (score 1):

here is the code from the link

```
//Namespace reference
using System;
using System.Resources;


#region ReadResourceFile
/// <summary>
/// method for reading a value from a resource file
/// (.resx file)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="file">file to read from</param>
/// <param name="key">key to get the value for</param>
/// <returns>a string value</returns>
public string ReadResourceValue(string file, string key)
{
    //value for our return value
    string resourceValue = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        // specify your resource file name 
        string resourceFile = file;
        // get the path of your file
        string filePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
        // create a resource manager for reading from
        //the resx file
        ResourceManager resourceManager = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager(resourceFile, filePath, null);
        // retrieve the value of the specified key
        resourceValue = resourceManager.GetString(key);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        resourceValue = string.Empty;
    }
    return resourceValue;
}
#endregion
```

I did not write the code it came from

http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1683.htm

HTH

bones

Answer (score 1):

I have a zip file loaded as a resource, and referencing it directly from the namespace gives me bytes, not a string.  Right-click on your file in the resources designer, and change the filetype from text to binary.  Then you will get a bytearray, which you could load into a MemoryStream.